# Why does the AlertDialog crash on show()?

Tags: android

I'm new to AlertDialogs and cannot get it to work with Cursors. The code below is in my onCreate() function and I know the Cursor has rows in it. Am I missing part of the creation code?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose a playlist");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

// Add cursor items
alertDialogBuilder.setCursor(cursor, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();
```

Cursor Builder:

```
private Cursor getPlaylists() {
    String[] ARG_STRING = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC
    };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                               ARG_STRING,
                                               null,
                                               null,
                                               null);

    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + cursor.getString(nameColumn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: So... what error? Logcat, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. I meant the code to look as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose a playlist");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

// Add cursor items
alertDialogBuilder.setCursor(cursor, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);


// show it
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

That should work. Can you show your logcat if it doesn't?

Comment: Removing that line will cause `alertDialog` to be null, throwing an NPE on the next line. If you said "replace that call with one to `alertDialogBuilder.show()` because that will create and show it", you might have a good answer, but you might want to explain it a bit, also.

Comment: changing the last few lines to `alertDialogBuilder.show()` causes the same error.

Comment: Hmm... says failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 241 rows, 4 columns.

Comment: K, update: changing MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME to MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID seemed to make it work, but I need the names...

Answer (score 0):

In Cursor Builder, you're trying to get the index of a column which you did not query.

```
int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION);
```

Four columns are requested for your query, which does not include MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION that you're trying to access:

```
String[] ARG_STRING = {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC
};
```

To fix this, simply add MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION to ARG_STRING.

Comment: Sorry, that was just to test stuff. I didn't actually use that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Strings starting with numbers break it. Changing

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
```

to

```
"" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
```

fixes it.